# Передача одного и того же motion event во все пункты списка

Tags: android, listview, adapter, ontouchlistener

Есть listview, где каждый пункт состоит из TextView и CustomView. 
XML каждого пункта:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<net.manualuser.calibr.TimeScale
    android:id="@+id/my_scale"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="40dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

TimeScale (CustomView) - шкала, которая прокручивается по горизонтали.

Нужно, чтобы при прокрутке любой шкалы из списка остальные прокручивались одновременно с ней. Если правильно понимаю, нужно передать motion event в TimeScale каждого пункта в списке.

Фрагмент кода адаптера:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = view;
    if(view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_scale_item, viewGroup, false);
    }

    scale = (TimeScale)v.findViewById(R.id.my_scale);

    scale.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            scale.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    });

    TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.counter);
    text.setText(Cities.get(i));
    return v;
}
```

При запуске получаю вот что: в списке из двух пунктов при прокрутке шкалы из первого пункта, вторая прокручивается вместе с ней, но не наоборот (как будто не установился ontouchlistener на вторую шкалу). В списке из трех: первая прокручивает еще вторую, вторая - еще третью, третья только сама себя. Т.е. при любом количестве пунктов в списке одновременно прокручиваются только две шкалы.

Прошу подсказки, что делаю неправильно.

Comment: `scale.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            scale.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    });`
Получается что вы слушаете OnTouch на вью и на **том** **же** **самом** **вью** вызываете onTouchEvent. Оно точно так надо?

Comment: @lllyct экспериментировал с этим кастом вью вне списка: В layout MainActivity вставил два таких вью, но с разными id. А в MainActivity повесил на них OnTouchListener, правда через реализацию интерфейса: scale.setOnTouchListener(this) и scale1.setOnTouchListener(this), а в onTouch методе передал один и тот же motion event на оба кастом вью: scale.onTouchEvent(event) и scale1.onTouchEvent(event). При таком варианте при прокрутке любого вью оба двигаются одновременно.

Comment: У вас `scale` это поле адаптера. При создании каждого отдельного вью туда записывается ссылка на TimeScale этого самого последнего вью.
При скролле первого элемента, в scale записан второй (если у вас их всего 2), и все работает. А при скроле второго, в scale записан он же.

Comment: То есть вам нужно каким-то образом создавать список из TimeScale всех элементов listview и вызывать onTouchEvent для каждого из них. И при этом нельзя забывать что listview использует одни и те же лайауты повторно, заполняя их новыми данными. Т.е. добавлять элементы в массив прокручиваемых TimeScale нужно только когда view == null